# Как реализовать перетаскивание блоков с помощью js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Необходимо реализовать сортировку блоков. Ярким примером того что нужно сделать есть сайт vk.com. В разделе альбомы с фотографиями, в конкретном альбоме можно перетаскивать фото на разные места, изменяя таким образом их позицию в сортировке. Вопрос как лучше всего это сделать? возможно есть какая то готовая библиотека.

Знаю про [jqueryui sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) но мне кажется что она может сортировать только по вертикали? А мне нужно реализовать сортировку в таком формате как на фото: [image: Фото1]
[image: Фото где захватил элемент для перетаскивания]

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid есть более симпатичный плагин, но не могу вспомнить название =/

Comment: https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/, https://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html - и прочие которые выдает гугл по запросу "drag grid jquery"

Comment: спасибо! Даже первый вариант подходит. Я как то не понял что у них есть подраздел для display-grid